# Подсчет суммы на JS

Tags: javascript

Имею такие строки с товаром:

```
    <tr id="t_1">
        <td><input type="number" id="p1" value="250"></td>
        <td><div id="p2">0.05</div></td>
        <td><div id="p3">12.5</div></td>
        <td><button type="button">В корзину</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="t_2">
        <td><input type="number" id="p1" value="250"></td>
        <td><div id="p2">15</div></td>
        <td><div id="p3">3750</div></td>
        <td><button type="button">В корзину</button></td>
    </tr>
```

Если изменить p1  то в p3 нужно вывести результат (p1 * p2) Подскажите как реализовать данную функцию, и отправить данные всех id из определенного tr на сервер пост запросом?

Comment: юзайте Knockout.js, там такие вещи делаются элементарно. Ну либо по-старинке - получать значения из элементов и записывать их в третий (что впрочем, хоть и менее удобно, но делается еще проще)

Comment: да я понимаю что нужно получить и записать, только вот с JS у меня проблем :))) Мне бы пример, я б там решил дальше.

Comment: @wwwplaton, скажите, а это вы только в примере сделали наигрубейшую ошибку, задав одинаковые id для нескольких элементов или же в реальном проекте у вас классы или другие селекторы?

Comment: да, это только в примере :) так то я понимаю это. но все же не все идет как хотелось, и onChange в хроме и IE не пашет. Печаль :((

Comment: @wwwplaton, могу вам частично помочь. Смотрите [такой вариант][1]. На больше - нет сегодня сил.

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/qwyGZ/7/

Comment: ого, так это уже все готовое. я так лентяем стану :D Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

```
<tr id="t_1">
<td><input type="number" id="p1" value="250" onChange="edit_p3();"></td>
<td><div id="p2">0.05</div></td>
<td><div id="p3">12.5</div></td>
<td><button type="button">В корзину</button></td>
</tr>

function edit_p3() {
var a = document.getElementById('p1').value;
var b = document.getElementById('p2').innerHTML;
var c = a * b;
document.getElementById('p3').innerHTML = c;
}
```

Comment: Благодарю, вот это я понимаю ответ:)))

Comment: даже в чистом js старайтесь не использовать инлайн обработчики, пользуйтесь подпиской на события. `document.getElementById('p1').addEventListener('input', function(){....});` и т.п.